# bandwidth kernel density estimation via cross validation

Tags: cross-validation

When doing cross validation for estimation of bandwidth in kernel density estimators, we can use

$$\arg \max_h \sum_{i} \log f_h^{-i}(x_i)$$

where $i$ is the index of the data, and $f_h^{-i}$ is the kernel density estimator fitted on all data-points **except** $x_i$.

So we are essentially just choosing the $h$ that maximizes the log-likelihood.

The problem is that for certain values of $x_i$, $f_h^{-i}(x_i)$ might be zero. This will happen if $x_i$ is distant enough from the remainder of the data and if we are using a Kernel which is supported on a interval like $[-1, 1]$ (like the Uniform kernel).

In this case, the entire sum is $-\infty$, and the cross-validation breaks down.

So how is this statistic then usable for LOOCV?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a problem here: because the sum is $-\infty,$ the likelihood itself is zero and therefore cannot possibly be at a maximum.  Because a sufficiently large bandwidth (e.g., one equal to the range of all data) gives a well-defined and *strictly positive* likelihood, you know this particular value of $h$ cannot maximize the likelihood.  Any decent solver will then search larger bandwidths $h.$

Comment: My question is more about whether this is something we actually want. Imagine your data is simulated from $N(0, 1)$ and then you add one outlier value of $x_i = 1000$. Now, if you estimate $h$ using this cross-validation, you are being forced to take $h$ to be extremely large, since otherwise the likelihood will be zero due to the point $x_i$. Now your kernel density estimator is a terrible fit across the entire data, whereas if you had picked a smaller $h$, it would've been abetter fit. Yes, it would estimate $f(x_i) = 0$ which is wrong ... but the true $f(x_i)$ probably *is* close to 0...

Comment: The LOOCV cross-validation will nicely detect that circumstance, so I still don't see what the problem is.